# Python2.7, the use of import matplotlib results in function output being assigned to a list twice

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been testing the use of an accumulate function in the following python code. This code works well in producing the correctly accumulated output, however it assigns the output to the list "test" twice. If I comment out 'import matplotlib', it only assigns it once. I need to use matplotlib for the rest of the code I'll be developing. I'd appreciate if anyone has some suggestions about why this might be/ a workaround? Thanks:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import math
from itertools import groupby, islice

def accumulate(iterable): # in py 3 use itertools.accumulate
    ''' Simplified version of accumulate from python 3'''
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total += element
        yield total
    print total

x=[1,2,3,4]

test=list(accumulate(x))

print "test: ", test  # why does this print twice when matplotlib is imported?
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't when I save this code in a text file named "test.py" with chmod 755 and run with "./test.py" on my linux box. I get

```
10
test:  [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

the 10 presumably comes from the line

```
print total
```

If I comment out the line

```
import matplotlib
```

it gives the same output

Comment: That should be comment, not an answer

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I wonder if it's something local to my system, the output I get is: `./test.py
3
6
10
test:  [1, 3, 6, 10]
3
6
10
test:  [1, 3, 6, 10]`

Comment: sorry.. I would make it a comment, except I need 50+ rep to do so :(